# How to create a buffer zone for notification

Tags: postgis, geoserver, buffer

I am working on a project, for this I need to find out abutter notification that generates a list of properties within the buffer zone from the selected property with user input distance in radius and generate a mailing list of each property displayed by the buffer result.

We are using GeoServer server and PostGIS, and need to do this on the server side coding and display result in OpenLayers viewer. Can anyone guide me with PostGIS spatial query to find  parcels from the selected parcels?

Distance measured for this is from the parcel outline not from the center of property.

I am new to PostGIS.

Answer (score 1):

The first steps to to perform this process are:

```
SELECT 
 a.abutters, 
 ST_Intersection(a.geom, ST_Buffer(b.geom, 1000)) as plot
 ST_Distance(a.geom, b.geom) as distance_to_project
FROM 
 addresses as a,
 project as b
WHERE
 ST_Intersects(a.geom, ST_Buffer(b.geom, 1000)) -- assuming a 1000m radius
```

This will give you a list of abutters, the plots that are affected, and the distance. This assumes that you have two tables `addresses` and `project` both which have a geometry column called `geom`.

Comment: ST_DWithin is a better choise than the combination of intersects and buffer since buffering is a quite expensive operation.

Answer (score 0):

As [Nicklas](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/960/nicklas-av%C3%A9n) pointed out in a comment; You should use [ST_DWithin](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_DWithin.html) which performs better.

With the example from the other posted answer.

```
SELECT 
 a.abutters
FROM 
 addresses a,
 project b
WHERE
 ST_DWithin(a.geom, b.geom, 1000)
```

Assuming that a and b geom have the same spatial reference using meter units.